# Reading value from Service method in spring batch

Tags: java, angular, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch, spring-restcontroller

It is my first user of spring batch. I want to get in every hour the stock of a product that designed by reference and id as List<Map<Date,Long>> to draw the graph of evolution of this product using angular google charts this is my service method

```
@Override
public Long getStockByRef(String ref, Long id) {
    Iterable<Produit> MyProducts = storeService.getAllProductOfStore(id);
    Long stock = 0L;
    for (Produit produit : MyProducts) {
        if(produit.getReference().equals(ref)) {
            stock =  produit.getStock();
        }
    }
    return stock;
}
```

This is My RestController

```
@GetMapping("products/{id}/stock/{ref}")
public Long getStockByRef(@PathVariable Long id, @PathVariable String ref) {
    Long stock = produitService.getStockByRef(ref, id);
    return stock;
}
```

My Spring batch class config

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class SpringBatchConfig {

    @Autowired private ProduitService produitService;
    @Autowired private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    @Autowired private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
    @Autowired private ItemReader<Long> itemStockReader;
    @Autowired private ItemWriter<List<Map<Date,Long>>> itemStockWriter;
    @Autowired private ItemProcessor<Long, List<Map<Date,Long>> > itemStockProcessor;

     @Bean
     public Job myJob() {
         Step step1 = stepBuilderFactory.get("step-get-stock")
                .<Long,List<Map<Date,Long>>>chunk(1)
                .reader(itemStockReader)
                .processor(itemStockProcessor)
                .writer(itemStockWriter)
                .build();
        
           return jobBuilderFactory.get("data").start(step1).build();
    }
}
```

How can I write My ItemReader ItemProcessor and my Itemwrite to return List<Map<Date,Long>> and send it via a @GetMapping?

Comment: do you really need spring batch for this task?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine Have you got any other suggestion I dont know I am junior in Spring ? how can I repeat  my getMapping every hour ?

Comment: I think you can use cronjob or spring schedule to execute getMapping every hour.